# Question About NavigationBar

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

When we give the option ***Navigation Bar with prompt*** for a navigation bar, its height doubles with the items like titles and button being pushed into the bottom half. Is there a way that I can keep those at the top and add a label at the bottom part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that.